# Why the account password is passed without encryption

Tags: https, passwords

By a sniffer (Fiddler), I can check out the stream sent through my PC to network. Surprisingly, I found when I log in google's account (https), the password is sent in a clear text, e.g.

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth HTTP/1.1 
... 

Email=abc@gmail.com&**Passwd=12345678**
```

My question is: why the password is passed without encryption even with a https protocol?

Comment: Where did you see this information in Fiddler? Which option should be selected to see this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTPS encrypts the entire request and response.

However, you're telling Fiddler to decrypt using an untrusted root certificate.

In other words, you're MITMing yourself, and telling the browser to ignore the untrusted certificate.

Answer (score 4):

No, the password is not sent without encryption to Google as clear text. Google is using SSL, don't worry. But you installed Fiddler on your PC. When you did so, Fiddler registered a specific root level certificate on your computer and is able to decrypt the traffic between your web browser and the internet. By installing Fiddler, you explicitly granted this application the possibility to decrypt the traffic. So, yeah, anyone able to get administrator access to a PC is able to install a root level certificate to this PC and consequently is able to decrypt all traffic between this PC and the internet. What did you expect? How do you think trojans work?

But any man-in-the-middle attacks won't work because they won't be able to decrypt the SSL traffic between your web browser and the internet.

Comment: Thanks Darin. My understanding is that, the browser (application layer) sends the clear text which is captured by Fiddler, and then SSL encrypts the clear text, so finally, the data stream in the network is all encrypted data. Is that true?

Comment: No, your understanding is completely wrong. Let me explain how Fiddler works. When you run Fiddler, it registers a WebProxy in your WebBrowsr (yeah, take a look at your browser's Proxy settings), so your browser sends all traffic to the registered proxy first. And since Fiddler registered a root level certificate when you installed it, it is able to decrypt this traffic sent by the web browser. That's why you can see your password in plaintext in Fiddler -> because you explicitly granted Fiddler the possibility to do so by installing it.

Comment: So when you write `https://www.google.com` in the address bar of your webbrowser, since Fiddler registered as a proxy, this request is **NOT** sent to `google.com` by the browser. It is sent to `http://localhost:8080` where Fiddler is listening. It has the corresponding root level certificate installed in your browser and decrypts the traffic to show it in the UI. Then it sends it to Google. Now you understand how Fiddler is able to get your password in cleartext?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov : Sir, Where can we see this information in Fiddler? Which option should be selected to see this information?

Comment: @PankajGarg, what information are you talking about? What do you want to see? It's how Fiddler works. That's all. I really don't understand what you are talking about.

Comment: OK, I see. I'm a new hand in network, I'd like to ask one more question: when I input the password in google's textbox and click the "sign in" button, I think the password has already been encrypted, right? Because Fiddler has the root level certificate, it can decrypt the data stream into clear text.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov : Sir, let's say i log on to yahoo mail. i typed the username and password. as the owner of the thread said **Email=abc@gmail.com& Passwd=12345678** I searched in the fiddler for the incoming url. But the email along with password was nowhere present in the incoming urls. Please help

Comment: @PankajGarg, then you probably didn't search well enough.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I'm curious about the "corresponding root level certificate" of Fiddler, how does Fiddler do that?